# Razor debugger freezes while settting breakpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, debugging, razor, blazor, razor-pages

[ScreenShot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgZbL.png)

When I try to set a breakpoint on Razor Page code, it freezes with message "Determining breakpoint location".
Cleaning and rebuilding of the solution have no effect, VS restarting the same.

Could somebony help me to solve this problem?
I have no any idea what to do (

**[upd]**

At least the problem was solved with repairing the VS.
MrC aka Shaun Curtis, thanks for answers

Comment: Visual Studio 2019, without any extensions

Comment: I don't see the breakpoint in the code.  Is it in the Razor Markup?

Comment: Because i can't set it. Visual Studio freezes just at that moment I try to set breakpoint

Comment: So you've not preset a breakpoint.  So when you say try to set it, how do you try?  Point to a line an F9, click in the margin.  If so show us the line of code you are trying to set the break point on.

Comment: I've encountered the same bug/msg when opening a Blazor .NET 6 Project and then clicking on an open .razor file tab that has seemingly "corrupted" breakpoints. VS crashes. It helped to "Close all Tabs" (and deleted bin+obj and restarted for saftey, this is my go-to fix for all VS bugs.)